# Centrally track opened and closed windows in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, window

I need some virtual function/signal/event in a QApplication that centrally informs about any opened and closed window in the application (providing a pointer to the window object; including QMainWindow, QDialog, QWidget based windows).

This should work *without* manually registering all window instances and without manually manipulating each instance (e.g. by installing event filters or connections on each window object). 
Also it should not be necessary to sub-class the tracked windows from some interface class or similar.

So, what is the best way in Qt to track all opened and closed windows in an application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must overwrite the notify method of QApplication(or QGuiApplication):

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class Application: public QApplication
{
public:
    using QApplication::QApplication;
    bool notify(QObject *receiver, QEvent *e) override
    {
        if(receiver->isWindowType()){
            if(e->type() == QEvent::Show){
                qDebug()<< receiver << "show";
            }
            else if (e->type() == QEvent::Close) {
                qDebug()<< receiver << "close";
            }
        }
        return QApplication::notify(receiver, e);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Application a(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow m;
    QDialog d;
    QWidget w;
    m.show();
    d.show();
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**Update:**

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class Application: public QApplication
{
public:
    using QApplication::QApplication;
    bool notify(QObject *receiver, QEvent *e) override
    {
        if(receiver->isWidgetType()){
            QWidget *w = qobject_cast<QWidget *>(receiver);
            if(w->isWindow()){
                if(e->type() == QEvent::Show){
                    qDebug()<< w << "show";
                }
                else if (e->type() == QEvent::Close) {
                     qDebug()<< w << "close";
                }
            }
        }
        return QApplication::notify(receiver, e);
    }
};
```

Comment: What I tried is save/restore of window configurations. Turned out it does not work with this fine code due to Qt limitations: `isWindowType()` in Qt5 makes the receiver an object derived from QWindow (not QWidget as in Qt4). For QWidget applications the receiver is a QWidgetWindow. Q(Widget)Window does not implement `normalGeometry()` which is necessary for save/restore. Also QWidgetWindow is private API of Qt. So there is no legal way of accessing the underlying QWidget. I decided to use `isWidgetType()` instead. However this limits my code to QWidget based applications.

Comment: @Silicomancer 1) I have shown how to use with QWidget 2) What other types of windows do you want to work with?

Comment: Currently only QWidget based windows. So for the moment that is not a problem. But I added two more modification to your example: I compared the windowType() (to ignore things like tooltips) and I didn't use close events but hide events since I found that QDialog windows do NOT receive a close event on accept() or reject().

Comment: @Silicomancer if you want to refine the filter you should do a cast more: `if(QDialog * dialog = qobject_cast<QDialog *>(receiver)){/* is QDialog */ }`

Comment: Yes, I did so. Also I decided to skip spontaneous events that are also fired when minimizing/maximizing windows.